# How to pass Bitmap from activity to Adapter

Tags: android-studio, android-adapter, onactivityresult, main-activity

I want to pass a bitmap from one activity to an adapter.In my Main activity i have the following:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data!= null && data.getData() != null){
            filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //getting image from gallery
                Bitmap bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
                Log.i("GRAMP5:","PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST chamado");

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i("GRAMP6:","REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO chamado");
            setPic();//returns bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap2 = setPic();
        }
    }
```

I want to pass bitmap1/bitmap2 to an adapter.How can I accomplish this?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create `passBitmapData.java`

```
public class passBitmapData{
public Bitmap bitmap;


public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}
```

}

Setting Bitmap from Activity

```
public passBitmapData passBitmapData = passBitmapData;

passBitmapData.setBitmap(yourBitmap);
```

Getting Bitmap in Adapter:

```
public passBitmapData passBitmapData = passBitmapData;


Bitmap Bitmap = passBitmapData.getBitmap();
```